# How to do low pass filtering on a differential signal

Tags: filter, signal, differential, low-pass

If I have a differential signal on a pair of wires then how would I do a simple RC low pass filter on this differential signal?

Comment: Like any other signal, just duplicate the filters on both differentials?

Comment: Following up on what Andy aka provided, the + Source impedance and mismatches + the load impedance and mismatches + the parasitic capacitances and imbalances **ALL** matter, in achieving good/useful differential and common mode filtering.

Comment: Alternatively, an R in series in each leg, and C/2 from one leg to the other. Or combine them to get a capacitive delta (the best approach in noisy environments)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *how would I do a simple RC low pass filter on this differential
> signal?*

The simplest method: -

[image]

[Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219202/cutoff-frequency-of-low-pass-filter-with-two-resistors-differential-signal). This circuit only filters differential signals; if there is an in-phase signal (or interference) on both lines (called a common-mode signal/noise) it provides no filtering to it.

A more complex but effective method: -

[image]

Modified from this [Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116245/differential-filter-design). This filter provides differential and common mode filtering. C2 and C3 are the extras but, be aware that if the differential signal is required to remain highly "balanced" in nature, tolerances on C2 and C3 can displace the perfect symmetry at higher frequencies.